# Install iw for AR Drone

Tags: cross-compiling, ar.drone, iwconfig, mesh-network

I am involved in a project using a Parrot AR Drone 1.0 that I would like to attach an USB dongle to act as a mesh node. But for that I need to install a software called [iw](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/iw), which is like an improvement of iwconfig,

I am following the instructions of this [project](http://taghof.github.io/Navigation-for-Robots-with-WIFI-and-CV/blog/2012/01/13/Compiling-Code-For-The-ARDrone/)Hence I need to cross compile it for its ARM processor but I am struggling so much because of dependencies and overall inexperience in cross compiling. I made the bold move of transfer it from a Raspberry Pi which also has ARM, but seems it does not work.

Does anyone managed to do something similar?

Thanks, any help will be appreciated

Jordi